# R - create iterable list/dataframe from unique()

Tags: r, list, unique

I'd like to get the unique elements from a column. That seems straight forward. Both of these work, but I'm not getting the object type I'd like:

```
userlist <- as.list(somebigdf$username)
userlist <- unique(userlist)
```

or

```
userlist <- unique(somebigdf$username)
```

When I iterate through, I'm not getting the names:

```
for(i in 1:length(userlist)){
    cat(names(userlist[i]), '\n')
}
```

Returns blank spaces.

```
for(i in userlist){
    cat(i, '\n')
}
```

Returns integers.

The above function is just an example. I'll be using that but also matching the returned name in an if-else function.

The object types seem to be integers or an extended data.frame with lots of values for each name - which isn't what I want. I would really just like a list of strings something along the lines of userlist = c( the results from unique).

Edit -

This code will iterate correctly through the names:

```
for(name in unique(somebigdf$username)){
    cat(name, '\n')
}
```

Comment: I think you're confused by the function `names`. I don't think it does what you think it does. Try removing it.

Comment: `unique` returns a character vector of each unique value of the strings in username. `names` returns the name of the columns..

Comment: I'm baffled. You answered your own question with your edit. What's the problem?

Comment: Well, yes & no. I accomplished what I set out to do - but I didn't get the answer to the question as posed - how do I create some object (list, dataframe, whatever) from unique and then iterate through it? I'm happy to close the question but I've seen people get really hostile when it seemed the answer didn't fully align with the question.

Comment: "how do I create some object (list, dataframe, whatever) from unique and then iterate through it" But that's exactly what you did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm accepting my own answer. Namely, a working solution - this code will iterate correctly through the names:

```
for(name in unique(somebigdf$username)){
    cat(name, '\n')
}
```

If someone at a later date has a better answer that seems more in keeping with the question, I will be happy to accept that as the answer.